# How to stop console app after logCritical in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logging

I want my console application to stop after ILogger uses logError or logCritical. Is that possible ?

so for example, I have injected ILogger into a class which is suppose to get some results from an external api:

```
        public WebsiteApiServices(ILogger<WebsiteApiServices> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

im getting response from the external api:

```
public TransactionDetails GetResultsFromApi(HttpClient client, string txnHash){
    var jsonResponse = await GetJsonResponse(client, txnHash);

    TransactionDetails result = null;
    try
    {
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EtherscanTransactionByHashSuccessfulResponse>(jsonResponse).Result;
    }
    catch (JsonSerializationException)
    {
        var failReason = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EtherscanTransactionByHashFailedResponse>(jsonResponse).Result;
        switch (failReason)
        {
            case "Invalid API Key":
                _logger.LogCritical($"API response: \"{failReason}\"");
                State.ExitAndLog(new StackTrace(), _logger);
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

So if the API key is invalid I'd like my console app to exit code. I want this because this method is used repeatedly, so I don't want to keep sending invalid requests to the external API.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop"? Return an exit code? Bubble an exception up to the OS? This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). It doesn't make sense that your _logger_ should be halting the application when something exceptional happens. The logic itself should be causing that.

Comment: Are you on the main thread? Are there any other threads not marked _background_? Do you want to exit gracefully or crash and burn? Are you logging within an exception handler?

Comment: @gunr2171 Sorry, kinda new to posting in stackoverflow, hopefully I provided enough details after editing my post.

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes it's the main thread, I want to exit code completely so no other code after logging something Critical runs. I added more details in the post, hopefully that clarifies my problem a bit. Also I'm new to exception handling and logging, but if I'm not mistaken exception handler is used only in ASP.NET and I'm working with console application so not ASP.NET here I think ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=net-6.0

Comment: @HansPassant has the right answer. But you should read up on how exceptions work; they are used everywhere in the .NET world. For example if you just run `throw new Exception ("I want to quit now");`, and you don't have `try` and `catch` statements anywhere in your code, your program will effectively crash

Comment: @HansPassant and Flydog57 thats a lot of valuable information, thanks a lot (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible?

Yes, but it's extremely unusual. Normally, exceptional situations are indicated by throwing exceptions, and the application can decide how to handle those exceptions. E.g., you could have define a `InvalidApiKeyException` which would be thrown by your API code, and when the exception gets to the top level application code, the application would decide to exit.

That said, you *can* have critical logs shut down your application. The appropriate way to do that would be to [define your own logging provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) and have it call [`IApplicationLifetime.StopApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.iapplicationlifetime.stopapplication?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) when anything logs a critical message. Note that the application will not stop *immediately*; it will return normally from the `LogCritical` method and do a graceful shutdown.

If you want a hard-stop, then call [`Environment.FailFast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) instead of `StopApplication`. Note that when using `FailFast`, the critical message may not actually get *logged*, since many (most?) logging providers cache their logs and won't actually get a chance to flush that cache when the application immediately stops.